# Select number of data based of a specific node

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following piece of code

```
XmlDocument docu = new XmlDocument();
        docu.Load(file);
XmlNodeList lst = docu.GetElementsByTagName("name");
                        foreach (XmlNode n in lst)
                        {
                            string text = n.InnerText;
    var types = doc.Element("program").Element("program-function").Element("function").Descendants("type").Where(x => x.Value == text).Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();
    }
```

my xml is as follows

```
<program> 
  <program-function> 
    <function>
    <name>add</name> 
    <return-type>double</return-type> 
    <params> 
     <type>double</type> 
     <type-value>a</type-value> 
     <type>double</type> 
     <type-value>b</type-value> 
     <type>string</type> 
     <type-value>c</type-value> 
    </params> 
   <body> return a + b + c; </body> 
</function> 
  <function>
   <name>test</name> 
   <return-type>int</return-type> 
   <params> 
     <type>double</type> 
     <type-value>a</type-value> 
     <type>double</type> 
     <type-value>b</type-value> 
     </params> 
   <body> return a + b; </body> 
  </function> 
 </program-function> 
</program>
```

i need to be able to get the number of `<type>` for each `<name>`

result for add should be 3 = `types.count() = 3`
result for test should be 2 = `types.count() = 2`

any advice?

EDIT : If i want to retrieve each value inside `types`? ie. `add` should contain `a`,`b`,`c` and `test` should contain `a`,`b`. Would love to store it in an array for easier retrieval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Linq to Xml

```
 var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var functions = xDoc.Descendants("function")
                .Select(f => new
                {
                    Name = f.Element("name").Value,
                    Types = f.Descendants("type").Select(t=>t.Value).ToList(),
                    //Types = f.Descendants("type").Count()
                    TypeValues = f.Descendants("type-value").Select(t=>t.Value).ToList()
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: What if i want to retrieve each value inside `types`? ie. `add` should contain `a`,`b`,c` and `test` should contain `a`,`b`. would love to store it in an array for easier retrieval.

Comment: @user2248001 I updated the answer. But next time ask a complete question and not extend it comments... If you want array replace `ToList`s with `ToArray`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(your file);
var vals = doc.Element("program").Element("program-function").Elements("function");

var result = vals.Select(i => 
                     new { name = i.Element("name"), 
                           count = i.Elements("type").Count() }
```

Comment: What if i want to retrieve each value inside `types`? ie. `add` should contain `a`,`b`,c` and `test` should contain `a`,`b`. would love to store it in an array for easier retrieval.

Comment: @user2248001 that's a different question.